# Getting the current foreground activity without a context

Tags: android, android-activity, reflection, android-context

I've seen previous threads about getting the current foreground activity and I was wondering if it's possible to get it without a context and/or ActivityManager (by using reflection maybe?).
Is it possible?

Comment: Since with multi-window, there may be multiple foreground activities, I recommend that you reconsider your approach to whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you only want to check your own app's activities, this is possible. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare, with multi-window, do these activites have their own task and stack?

Comment: @FatihOzcan: Yes.